# The syntax for checking equality of a variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators

Want to know if there is an option to optimize (to make it more competently) the syntaxes of the comparison.

I have a simple code which checks the inputs to my function through the "if - else" conditional statements. I verify if the variable equals to one of the inputs or not using logical "OR" operator.

```
function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  if (card==2 || card==3 || card==4 || card==5 || card==6) {
    count+=1;
  }
  else if (card==7 || card==8 || card==9) {
count+=0;
  }
  else if (card==10 || card=="J" || card=="Q" || card=="K" || card=="A") {
    count-=1;
  }
  else {
  return "No such combination";
  }
  if (count>0) {
    return count + " " + "Bet";
  }
  else {
    return count + " " + "Hold";
  }
  // Only change code above this line
}

// Add/remove calls to test your function.
// Note: Only the last will display
cc(7); cc(8); cc(9);
```

I would like to know if I can replace this amount of "OR" operators with another syntaxes?
I know about "switch" method, but now I'm interested in particular this approach.

Comment: Argh... I do not understand... seems that the input is an array, like [1, 'A', ...] to be logic with the count operation... but your code is with just one card... which one is the exact problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
if ([2, 3, 4, 5, 6].includes(card)) {
  count += 1;
} else if ([7, 8, 9].includes(card)) {
  count += 0;
} else if ([10, "J", "Q", "K", "A"].includes(card)) {
  count -= 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks as the most convenient way for me!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object that maps card values to the amount to add to `count`:

```
const cards = {
    2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1,
    7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0,
    10: -1, J: -1, Q: -1, K: -1, A: -1
};
function cc(card) {
    if (card in cards) {
        count += cards[card];
        if (count > 0) {
            return count + " Bet";
        } else {
            return count + " Hold";
        }
    } else {
        return "No such combination"
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

```
if (card==2 || card==3 || card==4 || card==5 || card==6) {
count+=1;
```

can be changed to

```
if (card >= 2 && card <= 6) {
count+=1;
```

EDIT:
If you only want integers, you might want to add `card / 2 == 0`.

Comment: @Bafftek it can be also 3.5 and than we get false positive

Comment: In theory yes, but since this is a card game and decimal values are meaningless, you could just `trunc` the variable at the top of the function or elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, this looks pretty better for the conditions with numbers. But it won't work for the condition when I check J, Q, K unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like that to make it very readable

```
function cc(cards) {
    let all = [
        { cards : [2,3,4,5,6] : value : 1},
        { cards : [7,8,9]     : value : 0},
        { cards : [10,'J','Q','K','A'] : value : -1}
    ];

    return cards.reduce( (acc,card) => {
        let found = all.find( v => v.cards.indexOf(card) !== -1 );
        if ( !found ) throw 'No such combination';
        return acc + found.value;
    }, 0);
}
```

Sorry for the edit, I just realized that the input is an array...
You can just put the throw/hold test outside this function :)